# Rails How to display the data in a index page based on id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am newbie to rails what I am trying was in my controller I have two methods

there are

```
def index
 @books = Book.all
end
```

And My index.html looks like

```
       s.no     Name        author      
        1        rails       raj                        
        2        electronics ravi
```

And I would Like to change the view of my Index.html.erb as shown in the bottom

and in

```
def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
    book_rating = BookRating.where(:book_id =>@book.id)
    rating_size = book_rating.size
    @avg_satisfaction = book_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).sum.to_f/rating_size
    @count= book_rating.count
end
```

What I wanted to do is display the count and avg_satisfaction according to books on index page as follows

```
  s.no     Name        author      satisfaction    count  
    1        rails       raj                45         1
    2        electronics ravi               50         2
```

Please tell me how to do this, as I am unable to understand it. I am able to display in my show.html.erb but I want to display in my index.html.erb.

Please help me solve it.

```
My model for Books
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ratings, :through=> :users

    has_many :book_profiles
  has_many :profiles, :through => :book_profiles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_profiles, :allow_destroy => true

  has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
   :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"




end
```

mY BOOK RATINGS CONTROLLER

```
  class BookRating < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :Book
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Books List</h1>

<table id="book" border="3" layout= "fixed" width=" 100%"  >
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 33%" />
    <col style="width: 33%" />
    <col style="width: 33%" />

  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Logo</th>
    <th>Place</th>
    <th> RATING</th>
    <th> Rank</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>  
  <tr >
    <td><%= book.id%></td>
    <td><%= book.name %></td>
    <td><%=image_tag book.logo.url(:thumb)%></td>
    <td><%= book.place %></td>
    <td><%= book.satisfaction %></td>
    <td><%= book.rating %></td>
    <% if !current_user.blank? %>
      <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', book %></td>
    <%else%>
      <td><%= link_to 'VIEW', new_user_session_path,:class=>"login" %></td>
    <%end %>


  </tr>
<% end %>
 </colgroup>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'ADD New book', new_book_path %>
```

Comment: You have a space in `Book. all`. Should be `Book.all`.

Comment: You already have `@books = Book.all`, now you just need to add to your `views/books/index.htm.erb` to display that info. What does your current index.htm.erb view look like?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the space in `Book. all` that is preventing your `index.html.erb` from showing all the books? If you generated that code with `rails generate....` the table view should already be in `index.html.erb`.

Comment: Hi every thing is working fine with my index.html but I want to add the extra two columns there are satisfaction and count

Comment: Can you show us what `ìndex.html.erb` contains right now? The code, not the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you add `satisfaction` and `rating` instance methods in your `Book`model:

```
# app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def satisfaction
    book_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).sum.to_f/rating
  end

  def rating
    book_rating.count
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
# app/views/books/index.html.erb
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    ...
    <td><%= book.satisfaction %></td>
    <td><%= book.rating %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

And in your `BooksController` similar to your `index` action, your `show` action would just be:

```
# app/controllers/books_controller.rb
def show
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Update:** To display overall_rating, add this method in your `books` model:

```
# app/models/book.rb
def overall_rating
  ratings.sum('satisfaction + rating + view')/3
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    ...
    <td><%= book.overall_rating %></td>
    ...
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that is fine but I have a problem is I have more parameters how can I calculate it. I have parameters like (s1+s2+s3+s4)/rating. How do I get it.

Comment: @user3144005, I'm not sure I understand your parameters `(s1+s2+s3+s4)/rating`.  What are `s1`, `s2`...?

Comment: There are the different parameter asked to user to calulate over all rating of a book. Like satisfaction, quality, rating for author and so on.and I would like calculate the over all rating.

Comment: Don't you want to keep the ratings for different attributes separate?  Could you post your `models` and `views` in your question?

Comment: No I dont want individual  rating for different attributes I want over all ratings. sure I will post it.

Comment: I have added the models and views.

Comment: So what is `overall_rating`, is it just the sum of `satisfaction`, `quality` and `rating`.  Are these all columns in your `book_ratings` table?

Comment: Yes I have in these columns  and the sum of satisfaction, quality and rating divided by 3 with getting percentage.

Comment: i am getting the following error
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "satisfaction" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT SUM(satisfaction + rati...
                   ^
: SELECT SUM(satisfaction + rating + view) AS sum_id FROM "ratings"  WHERE "ratings"."company_id" = $1